# Google Apps Script - Format Column in Specific Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a Google Apps Script to automatically change the format for a specific column in a specific sheet or tab of my Google Sheets doc. I'm pretty new to Google Apps Scripts and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me out?

```
function myFunction() {
  var column = custom_tab_name.getRange {"D2:D");
  column.setNumberFormat ("@");
}
```

Comment: I think that your script is incomplete. For example, what is `custom_tab_name`? And, I think that when your script is saved, an error occurs because of `{"D2:D")`. So, in order to do that the users can correctly understood your question, how about providing the whole script for replicating your issue, and also, providing the detail of your current issue?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm a complete newbie here, so my apologies for not explaining properly.

What I'd like to do is to format the entire column of a specific sheet in my doc every time the data reloads (it loads every night due to a Supermetrics plugin). custom_tab_name is the name of the sheet that I want to the column to be formatted in. 

IE - I want column D in sheet custom_tab_name to be formatted by "@" every time it loads. Can you help me write a script for that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `the data reloads (it loads every night due to a Supermetrics plugin)`. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you update your question by including more detail information of your current issue and your goal?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,4,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()-1).setNumberFormat("@");
}
```